# Unable to write files through Spark Programs to Google cloud cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Unable to write files through Spark Programs to Google cloud cluster since two days. It was working fine earlier but now whenever i start my cluster i see some 200 jobs already submitted by someone named dr.who. I also tried calling Google Home Support but could not reach and talk to them.

Comment: This is definitely better taken care of by Google **Cloud Platform** support, not Google Home

Comment: You can go to the YARN or Spark UI to terminate applications, but someone might have hacked your cluster, so you might need a new account

Comment: Same here since a couple of weeks. When did your problem start?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam) to manage the users and permissions. If you see the user account dr.who, but do not recognize giving them permission to submit jobs, you can remove the account.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like someone hacked your cluster. We're having the same issue here since a couple of weeks.

[Google Cloud Dataproc Virus CrytalMiner (dr.who)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283049/google-cloud-dataproc-virus-crytalminer-dr-who/51383899#51383899)

Comment: Can you explain the -1?